# Finding all edit distance of all substrings

Tags: edit-distance

**Question**: Suppose $a, b$ are sequences with $n=|a|,m=|b|$ lengths, and $ed(a,b)$ denotes [edit distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance) between them. what is the complexity of computing $ed(a[i:j],b)$ for all values $1\le i<j\le n$?

**$O(n m)$ to compute $ed(a[1:i],b)$s**
Let $A$ denote the DP table with $(n+1)\times (m+1)$ size. For all $i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ and $j\in\{1,\dots,m\}$ put
$$
\begin{cases}
A_{0,0}\gets 0\\
A_{i,0}\gets i\\
A_{0,j}\gets j\\
A_{i,j}\gets \min\big\{1+A_{i-1,j},1+A_{i,j-1},A_{i-1,j-1}+\mathbf{1}_{[a_i\neq b_j]}\big\}
\end{cases}
$$
Observe that, at no additional cost, $ed(a[1:i],b)$ is computed in $A[i,m]$.

**$O(n^2 m)$ to compute $ed(a[i:j],b)$s** By repeating the same process for all $(a[i:n],b),i\in\{1,\dots,n\}$ we can compute all $ed(a[i:j],b)$s in $O(n^2 m)$ time.

I wonder if there is a smarter way to exploit the subproblems, and have a better time complexity?